# This Xbox signing out thing makes absolutely no sense

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

In my area there is currently an outage where I can’t connect to Xbox Live or the internet but I can still play games as long as I am signed in to my account. However, I get randomly signed out when I was previously signed in while not connected to WiFi. Why is this happening and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common problem. [This thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/xboxone/comments/777b1o/keep_getting_signed_out_even_offline/) on Reddit lists a couple of possible causes and fixes:

- Someone else is trying to log in to your account. You can try changing your password.
- Your controller might try to log in inadvertently. Try turning this feature off.
- The Xbox Companion app might cause this problem. Try uninstalling it.
- Try updating your controller.
- Try hard-resetting your console.

Additional solutions taken from [here](https://motorolamentor.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003103393-I-keep-getting-disconnected-and-kicked-out-from-Xbox-Live):

- Try powering down and leaving your console unplugged for at least 5 minutes to clear out memory.
- Disconnect third-party headsets or other wireless connections that might interfere.
- Reset your router by powering off and replugging.